# Singly linked list updating head to point to itself?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to represent a singly linked list in C++. I'm adding two elements at the head of the list, 4 and 34. I also have a print method, to print the contents of the linked list.

I have an incorrect head update somewhere, because the print method enters an infinite loop. I tried debugging with breakpoints, and that lead me down the following rabbit hole:

During the second insertion: s.insert(34), I somehow change the value of head to 34, when creating a node for 34. Can someone help me understand how that happened?

Or am I missing the picture entirely? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node {
    public:
    Node* next;
    int key;
    Node(int k) : key(k), next(nullptr) {}; //on s.insert(34), this changes head to 34
};

class SinglyLinkedList {
    public:
        Node* head;
        SinglyLinkedList() : head(nullptr) {};
        void insert(int);
        void print();
};


void SinglyLinkedList::insert(int x) {
    Node n =  Node(x);
    if (head == nullptr) {
        head = &n;
    }
    else {
        n.next = head; // head already points to 34 at this point
        head = &n;
    }
}   

void SinglyLinkedList::print() {
    for (Node *i = this->head; i != nullptr; i = i->next)
        cout << i->key << endl;
}

int main(){
    SinglyLinkedList s = SinglyLinkedList();
    s.insert(4);
    s.insert(34);
    s.print();
}
```

Comment: In your `insert(int x)` method, you declare a local variable `n` and then set `head` to point to `n` -- but since `n` is a local variable, it is automatically destroyed when `insert()` returns, so your `head` pointer is going to be a dangling pointer and will invoke undefined behavior if/when you try to dereference it.  Unless you meant to type `Node * n = new Node(x);` instead?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Thank you!!! That worked like a charm. I've been staring at this for hours, I forgot how badly pointers can burn you if you aren't careful. I appreciate the help! :)

Comment: Even after that is fixed, note how both `if` and `else` sections end with reassigning `head`. So.. get rid of both and put that after the if-else. Then you'll realize that `head` equating to null on entrance also doesn't matter, since your pushing new elements to the head of the list anyway. Therefore, that whole function deduces to (1) allocate a node, (2) set its `next` to the current `head`, and (3) set `head` to the just-allocated node. Done. Also, `SinglyLinkedList s = SinglyLinkedList();` is redundant. Just `SinglyLinkedList s;` is adequate.